# What is the best way to sort items on one of the items values

Tags: python

I have two instances of an object in a list

```
class Thing():
     timeTo = 0
     timeFrom = 0
     name = ""

o1 = Thing()
o1.name = "One"
o1.timeFrom = 2

o2 = Thing()
o2.timeTo = 20
o2.name = "Two"

myList = [o1, o2]


biggestIndex = (myList[0].timeFrom < myList[1].timeTo) & 1
bigger  = myList.pop(biggestIndex)
lesser  = myList.pop()

print bigger.name
print lesser.name
```

both o1 and o2 have two properties that I want to compare the first in the lists timeFrom property and the second ones timeTo property to eachother.

I feel this is a bit awkward and wierd, is there perhaps a better and more readable approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to make `Thing` instances *sortable*. You do this by implementing `__lt__`:

```
class Thing():
     timeTo = 0
     timeFrom = 0
     name = ""

     def __lt__(self, other):
         return self.timeFrom < other.timeTo


lesser, bigger = sorted(myList)
```

Python2 has `lesser, bigger = sorted(myList, cmp=lambda one,other: one.timeFrom < other.timeTo)`.

In Python3 `cmp` is gone, I guess to force people to do (or learn) OOP and write a *adapter*.

```
class SortAdaper(object):
    def __init__(self, obj ):
        self.obj = obj

class TimeLineSorter(SortAdaper):
    """ sorts in a timeline """
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.obj.timeFrom < other.obj.timeTo

class NameSorter(SortAdaper):
    """ sorts by name """
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.obj.name < other.obj.name

print sorted( myList, key=TimeLineSorter)
print sorted( myList, key=NameSorter)
```

Comment: @Justin Ardini: That's a property of the metric the OP defined. o1 and o2 are simply not sortable in this case.

Comment: When you have `o1.timeFrom >= o2.timeTo` and `o2.timeFrom >= o1.timeTo` and you want that `o1.timeFrom <= o1.timeTo` ( which is very reasonable given the variable names ) then this implies (do the math!) that `o2.timeFrom >= o2.timeTo` ... and that makes no sense!

Comment: Perfect! I ended up writing a sorter and using it as key argument to the sorted function, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

see [attrgetter](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html?highlight=attrgetter#operator.attrgetter)

```
import operator

getter = operator.attrgetter('timeFrom')

bigger = max(myList, key=getter)  
lesser = min(myList, key=getter)

print bigger.name  
print lesser.name
```

EDIT :

**attrgetter** also wokrs with **sorted** or anywhere a **key** function is needed.

```
lesser, bigger = sorted(myList, key=getter)
```

Comment: +1, `operator.attrgetter` is definitely the right approach (but **please** edit this A to do it right: start with `import operator` and use `operator.attrgetter` explicitly -- doing otherwise is not only debatable style, but _sure_ to leave beginners terribly perplexed as Python gives them a "name not found" error!!!).

Comment: The OP wants to sort by comparing *two attributes* so this cannot work (and it doesn't give the right result).

Comment: as THC4k said, I need to compare one attribute to another attribute, is there a way to make this fit my need of comparing one attibute to another?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this, if object can have only one of the time values:

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, name, time = 0, timename = 'to'):
        self.name, self.time, self.timename = (name,time,timename)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Thing(%r, %i, %r)" % (self.name, self.time, self.timename)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.time < other.time

o1 = Thing("One", 5, 'from')

o2 = Thing("Two", 20, 'to')

myList = [o1, o2]

print myList
print max(myList)
print min(myList)
```